# qgis - how to sum value of field of other layer if intersecting polygon

Tags: qgis

I want to find the total length of ski runs of a specific difficulty (eg. beginner, advanced, etc) within a ski resort but cannot.

I have two layers.  One is a polygon layer called `ski_mountain`.  The other layer is a line layer called `ski_run`.

`ski_run` each row of data has `run_difficulty` and `run_length`. `run_difficulty` consists of 4 distinct values like *beginner*, *intermediate*, *advanced* and *expert*.  `run_length` is the length of the `ski_run` in km.

I would like to add 4 calculated fields called to `ski_mountain` call `beginner`, `intermediate`, `advanced` and `expert` which should container the summed length of each `ski_run` if it is located in the polygon for `ski_mountain`.

Here is where I stumble.  The below calculated field will calculate the entire table of `run_length` of all rows whereas I just want the `run_length` within each polygon of `ski_mountain`.

```
aggregate(
    layer:='ski_run',
    aggregate:='sum',
    expression:= "run_length",
    filter:= "run_difficulty" = 'beginner'
)
```

I know there is another function called `overlay_within` or `overlay_intersects` that could help but I am not sure who to put `aggregate()` and `overlay_intersections()` together to do this...if this is the best way to do it.